# Webpack bundler

Tags: reactjs, webpack, content-management-system

I am currently looking into React, React-habitat, and Webpack.

My question is does Webpack also bundle the index.html file where I reference the bundle or is this kept separate? Is it possible to exclude this without specifically stating this in the Webpack config file?

this is the current structure am envisioning.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT6xw.jpg

I know that all the dependencies found in my entry file for Webpack are bundled. The reason I would like to know this is because I am doing some research on how a CMS can be built around the three topics I mentioned above. I need to know if the index.html file is also bundled or not because I would like to edit the original index file(if it is not bundled) instead of repackaging everything for every change.

Hope someone understands what am looking for.

Comment: Webpack does not bundle the index.html file, so for example if you had the CMS wordpress. You could create an app locally testing it with the index.html and then when you want to add it to your cms, you can just take the script tag and div tag in the index.html file and add it to your wordpress template and the app will run. Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you that is what I needed to hear

Comment: @SpencerBigum comment is the answer!